# Describe closure and interior of subspace $A$ of $X \times B$ in terms of interior and closure of his projection in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ any topological space and $B$ a topologic space consisting in $\{0,1\}$ with banal topology. 
My question is to describe closure and interior of subspace $A$ of $(X \times B)$ in terms of interior and closure of his projection in $X$.
At first, I thought to define the projection of $A$ in $X$, but I don't know how define it.

Comment: Do you consider the trivial or the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Define banal topology

Comment: @Babelfish trivial topology

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't understand. In Banal topology the only ones open are empty set and {0,1}

Comment: @Giusy do you know how the closed sets in $X\times B$ look like? // I think the injections $i_0 \colon X\to X\times B, x\mapsto (x,0)$ and $i_1 \colon X\to X\times B, x\mapsto (x,1)$ should be more helpful than the projections $p_X\colon X\times B \to X, (x,b)\mapsto x$ or $p_B\colon X\times B \to B, (x,b)\mapsto b$.

Comment: okay, but how I define closure and interior of subspace A of (X x B) in terms of interior and closure of the injection i_0 for example??

Comment: what do you even mean by "interior and closure of the injection"? \\ Do you know how the closed sets in $X\times B$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1.  A is empty.
Case 2.  A = D×{a}, a = 0 or 1.
. . A$^o$ is empty, $\overline A$ = $\overline D$×B.

Case 3.  A = D×{0} $\cup$ E×{1}.
. . $\bar A$ = $\overline{D×\{0\}} \cup \overline{E×\{1\}}$
. . = $\bar D×B \cup \bar E×B$
. . = ($\bar D$ $\cup$ $\bar E)×B$
. . = $\overline {D \cup E}×B$.

A$^o$ = (D $\cap$ E)$^o$×B

Comment: in the third case is closure of A equal to closure of (D U E) x B?

Comment: @Giusy.  See edit.

Comment: I saw it, thank you.